# Question about day repeat function in iPhone alarm app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing the day repeat feature of the iPhone alarm app.

I want to use Bitmask to set Monday (1), Tuesday (2), Wednesday (4), Thursday (8), Friday (16), Saturday (32), Sunday (64), and day of the week.

When I use this method, I get 0 ~ 127, 128 combinations of day settings.

```
fileprivate func convertSchedule(_ schedule: Int) -> String {
        switch schedule {
        case 0: return "none"
        case 1: return "Every Monday"
        case 2: return "Every Tuesday"
        case 3: return "mon,tue"
        case 4: return "Every Wednesday"
        case 5: return "mon,wed"
        case 6: return "tue,wed"
        default: break
        }
        return ""
}
```

This code converts a number from 0 to 127 into the day of the week string. I thought it was too inefficient to write all 128 cases in code.

Can you make this function simple?
Instead of coding all 128 cases,

Comment: First you need to decide how is that converted string created (think about edge cases). Then you can use bitwise operators to figure out which days are scheduled and construct the string based on that. Definitely don't create 128 case statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with the bitmask. You can extract the days to repeat from the schedule and then base on the number of days, construct the string. for example, you can refer to my example below:

```
struct WeekDay {
  let rawValue: Int
  let name: String

  static let mon = WeekDay(rawValue: 1, name: "Monday")
  static let tue = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<1, name: "Tuesday")
  static let wed = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<2, name: "Wednesday")
  static let thu = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<3, name: "Thursday")
  static let fri = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<4, name: "Friday")
  static let sat = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<5, name: "Saturday")
  static let sun = WeekDay(rawValue: 1<<6, name: "Sunday")

  static let all: [WeekDay] = [.mon, .tue, .wed, .thu, .fri, .sat, .sun]
  func isIncluded(in schedule: Int) -> Bool {
    return schedule & rawValue == rawValue
  }
}

fileprivate func convertSchedule(_ schedule: Int) -> String {
  var daysToRepeat = WeekDay.all.filter({ $0.isIncluded(in: schedule) })

  if daysToRepeat.count == 0 {
    return "none"
  } else if daysToRepeat.count == 1 {
    return "Every \(daysToRepeat[0].name)"
  } else {
    return daysToRepeat.map({ $0.name }).joined(separator: ",")
  }
}
```

Comment: This might all be cleaner using `OptionSet`.

Comment: I know, but it is better to have `name` as a property of the model. Using an optionSet will make the computed var `name` is quite complex. Anyway, I think a struct still works very well here. If you have any solution with optionSet please post it. I'd like to know